# How can I use python3 in sublime3?

Tags: python-3.x

I started studying the book'python crash course'.  I studied setting up Python3 in sublime text, but it doesn't run properly.  Here is the code:

```
{
     "cmd":["python3","-u","$file"]
}
```

I set this code to python3 in the build system. And I tried to run "hello python world!":

```
print("Hello Python world!)
```

I've tried selecting and running Python3 from my code in the build system, but it doesn't work.
I don't know why it doesn't work. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are actually calling the **Python interpreter** in the command line.

On **Windows**, Python is normally referenced as **py** if it was added to **%PATH%** during installation.
On **Linux or macOS** Python 3 is normally referenced as **python3**.

To add Python to %PATH%, run the Python installer again, click **"Modify"**, then activate **"py launcher"**, click **"Next"** and **"Install"**.

Use on **Windows**:

```
{
    "cmd":["py", "-u", "$file"]
}
```

**Linux / macOS**:

```
{
    "cmd":["python3", "-u", "$file"]
}
```

PS: I don't know if your Python code just has a typo here in the question, but there seems to be missing one double quote. If you are getting error messages containing **"Syntax Error"**, forget about the py launcher. There's just a syntax error in your code. Use:

```
print("Hello Python World!")
```

Comment: Thank you!! But I clicked modify and activated 'py launcher', but when I run Python again, the function that was activated is turned off. I also activated it and tried running it, but it still doesn't print "Hello Python world".  My screen looks like this:

Comment: When I enter the above code in the build system and click Python 3 and try to print 'Hello Python world', the message [WinError 2] FileNotFoundError appears.

Comment: PS: There was a quote typo in my question.  There were no typos in my program.  Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Are you able to launch a Python shell by typing *py* into cmd?

Comment: Yes. I can launch a Python shell by typing py into cmd.

Comment: I'm currently struggeling to recreate your issue, sorry. I'll add a comment if I make progress on this. Or have you solved it yet?